# Iterate though range of IP addresses

Tags: vb.net, ip-address

I need an elegant way using VB.Net to iterate through a range of IP addresses when the input will come to my app as a string in this format:

```
192.168.100.8-10
```

This range would include 3 addresses:

```
192.168.100.8, 192.168.100.9, 192.168.100.10.
```

I found a solution in C# that uses the IP Address class that I could probably convert to VB but it seemed to be way too much code for what I need to do. I could definitely use a bunch of string parsing functions but I was hoping someone already had a simple way of doing this.

Comment: This seems like a relatively simple programming exercise, just grab the last bit through a RE, parse out the '-' to get the min/max values, do a little error checking (x < y && both > 0 and < 255) and you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution.  It would be even easier using generic lists...

```
    Dim arrFinalIpList() As String

    Dim strIP As String = "192.168.100.8-10"

    Dim arrIP() As String = strIP.Split(".")
    Dim strPrefix As String = arrIP(0) & "." & arrIP(1) & "." & arrIP(2) & "."
    Dim arrMinAndMax() As String = arrIP(3).Split("-")

    Dim intCursor As Integer = 0

    For intCursor = CInt(arrMinAndMax(0)) To CInt(arrMinAndMax(1))

        If arrFinalIpList Is Nothing Then

            ReDim arrFinalIpList(0)
            arrFinalIpList(0) = strPrefix & intCursor.ToString()

        Else

            ReDim Preserve arrFinalIpList(arrFinalIpList.Count)
            arrFinalIpList(arrFinalIpList.Count - 1) = strPrefix & intCursor.ToString()

        End If

    Next
```